# 2018 Unity Void Update () not updating second line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, int

So I'm making a Tamagotchi pet game and within the stats, the lines within 'Void Update()' only seem to update the stats first line in _Happiness and not in _hunger. Is there any reason why this might be happening? I also have one other script within my prototype relative to the stats.

```
public GameObject happinessText;
public GameObject hungerText;

public GameObject robot;
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    happinessText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + robot.GetComponent<Robot>().happiness;
    hungerText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + robot.GetComponent<Robot>().hunger;
    //happinessText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "" + robot.GetComponent<Robot>().happiness;
}
```

Other script:

```
public int _hunger;
public int _happiness;


void Start()
{ 
PlayerPrefs.SetString("then", "05/06/2016 11:20:12");
    updateStatus();
}



    void updateStatus()
{
   if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("_hunger"))
    {
        _hunger = 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_hunger", _hunger);

    } else {
        _hunger = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_hunger");
    }

    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("_happiness"))
    {
        _happiness = 100;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("_happiness", _happiness);

    } else {

        _happiness = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("_happiness");

    }

    if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("then")) //{
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("then", getStringTime());

        TimeSpan ts = GetTimeSpan();

        _hunger -= (int)(ts.TotalHours * 2);
        if (_hunger < 0)
            _hunger = 0;

        _happiness -= (int)((100 - _hunger) * ts.TotalHours / 5);

        if (_happiness < 0)
            _happiness = 0;

    }

public int hunger
{
    [OnSerialized]
    get { return _hunger; }
    set { _hunger = value; }
}

public int happiness
{
    [OnSerialized]
    get { return _happiness; }
    set { _happiness = value; }
}
```

Comment: Does the console show any error? 
What happens if you switch both the statements so that the hunger one is called first and then the happiness one?

Comment: What do you need the fields `hunger` and `happiness` for if `_hunger` and `_happiness` are public anyway?

Comment: What happens instead? Maybe the `hunger` value simply didn't change?

Comment: Btw don't use `GetComponent` in `Update` .. even better don't use it at all: instead of `GameObject` references make e.g. `public Robot robot`. The Unity inspector will than automatically use the `Robot` component as reference

Comment: Possible reason that your first line throwing an exception. Please ensure the objects are not null

Answer (score 0):

It seems the method `updateStatus` is only called once, in the `Start` method of the Other Script.

Looking at your scripts it seems you might missing the `Update()` function:

```
void Update()
{
    updateStatus();
}
```

I would also put a few breakpoints to the code where `_hunger` and `_happiness` is updated. Or put a few `Debug.Log(...)` calls there, if you prefer. The important thing would be to confirm that the values are updated regularly.

Comment: this block actually only wraps `if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("then")) 
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("then", getStringTime());` OP has it only bad intended

Comment: Ah yes, you are absolutely right. I'll remove that part.